# Grails Asset Pipeline, Ajax, and Templating

Tags: ajax, grails, asset-pipeline

I have some controllers in a Grails plugin that use the standard _form.gsp that gets referenced by index.gsp and edit.gsp. My form has some input elements that I want to get data via an AJAX call.

With the resources plugin, I could put an `<r:script>` tag in my page, the body of which could be javascript that contained gsp tags like `<g:createLink>`, which I could then use to set the url property of an AJAX block.

I've switched to the asset-pipeline plugin, and I'm somewhat flummoxed at the best way to accomplish the same thing. I want to declare that my form.gsp template has a dependency on a script that contains several ajax calls.

If I use the `<asset:script>` tag, then I can use `<g:createLink>` to make the URL, but the generated  tag ends up in the middle of the page body, even with the `<asset:deferredScripts />` call up in the head of the edit.gsp and index.gsp pages. If I use `<asset:javacript src="myscript.js"/>`, then I have to hard-code the URL of the controller into the javascript file, which I'd rather not do, since this is a plugin.

One workaround I've seen is for people to stick the needed URL in a data- attribute of some page element, then retrieve it in jQuery, or to set [a global javascript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25303987/1524502) that contains the serverURL.

Is there no better way?

Comment: What I'm doing for now is to put the application context (the main thing I need for urls in ajax) as a javascript variable in my main layout gsp. `<g:javascript> window.applicationContext = '${request.contextPath}'; </g:javascript>` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645240/create-link-to-resource-from-js-file

Not perfect, but it'll do.